# Trouble getting PyOpenGL to work on Windows

Tags: python, windows, opengl, glut, pyopengl

As many others, I tried installing PyOpenGL on Windows (pip install PyOpenGL works but no GLUT is installed).

On a previous install, I followed the most common instructions, by following this [link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)  and downloading and installing the .whs file with pip.

The issue is that the file is no longer hosted on that link. Every single website and forum question I found links to that site, so there seems to be no way to obtain them anymore.

- I tried using the .whs file on the PyOpenGL website, but it's the
  same as installing it directly with pip; it doesn't work.  I
  downloaded freeGLUT and copied the .dll where my .py file is, but it
  didn't work.  Another solution I found is adding the .bin\x64 folder,
  where the freeglut.dll, is to my system variables path didn't work
  either

EDIT: When I launch code using opengl, I get the following error:

```
OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glutInit, check for bool(glutInit) before calling
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are encountering? That glut is missing? Is there any error message?

Comment: Yes, glut is missing from the OpenGL installation. The common workaround doesn't work anymore and I cannot find an alternative solution that works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the site which has the unofficial wheels was archived and now is available. You can find it here (same link as before):

[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

I will close the question.